# SSH - run command in background & disconnect

Tags: linux, ssh

I need to copy a big file (about 30 Gb) in background via ssh. If I do it this way, and disconnect, it's copied well:

```
ssh server
# cp /file1 /file2 & >/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; disown;
```

But if I do this:

```
ssh server 'cp /file1 /file2 & >/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; disown;'
```

it waits until file copies. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `-f`:

```
ssh -f server 'cp /file1 /file2 & >/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; disown;'
```

(Tested and works for me.)

From the [man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1):

> -f Requests ssh to go to background just before command
>   execution.  This is useful if ssh is going to ask for passwords or
>   passphrases, but the user wants it in the background.  This implies
>   -n.  The recommended way to start X11 programs at a remote site is with something like ssh -f host xterm.

Comment: That's OK, but there is still one more problem - I can't async copy files via python-paramiko from my python code because it's behavior is like ssh binary without option '-f'

Comment: @user59178 - As the original question doesn't mention anything about python, I'd suggest posting this as a new question - and probably at http://stackoverflow.com.